# What is the purpose of AddFormatterMappings() on Asp.net Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core

I am evaluating the configuration of a Web API App with Asp.Net Core 2. To configure I know it is better for my project to use `.AddMvcCore()` rather then use `AddMvc()` since I don't need Razor as we can see [here](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/02/07/difference-between-addmvc-addmvcore/).

Now, I am not sure if I also need this `.AddFormatterMappings()`. So my question is what is it for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see from the [source code in the MVC GitHub repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1c4b0fcdf38320b2f02c0bb7c31df5bd391ace07/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L67) that it adds a [`FormatFilter`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c27b07ef3f8b07dfe1d1de38a8d7bf2d6a9298f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Formatters/FormatFilter.cs) service into the DI setup. The summary for the `FormatFilter` class is as follows:

> A filter that will use the format value in the route data or query
>   string to set the content type on an `ObjectResult` returned from an
>   action.